# Android | Debug native app on Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cpu-architecture, genymotion

When I try to debug native (cocos2dx game) on Genymotion (Nexus 7, android 4.3) emulator, I got:

> warning: while parsing target description (at line 1): Target description specified unknown architecture "i386"
>   warning: Could not load XML target description; ignoring

I understood the problem, but I don't know how to fix it?

Is there any possibility to spoof a cpu-arch on Genymotion emulator? Or maybe this problem can be solved by some different way?

**Update 1**
My Android.mk file have

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
```

Is far as I know `i365` kind of `x86`, so I'm still confusing why `gdb` fails

**Update 2**

The same problem descibed [here](http://www.unknownerror.org/Problem/index/-175860120/how-to-set-ndkcompatabi-for-eclipse-x86-android-jni-debugging/) and looks like the author have solved it

Comment: which gdb are you using? ndk-gdb or gdb from your distribution?

Comment: I'm using `ndk-dbg`. What do you mean by `gdb from your distribution`?

Comment: The update 2 link 404'd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by cleaning `obj` dir